# online PCA in python

Tags: python, pca

Does anyone know a python library which has online PCA estimations (something similar to what is described in this paper [online PCA](https://edoliberty.github.io//papers/opca.pdf))

Does it make sense to use the `sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA` method with `batch_size =1`.

Comment: what exactly is the goal ?

Comment: Any updates on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

You can check this out:

https://github.com/flatironinstitute/online_psp

It is not exactly PCA since components might be not orthogonal (you can easily orthogonalize them at need, there is also an object method to do so)

Cheers

DISCLAIMER: I am one of the developers of this project.

Comment: Is the project still maintained?